# "Guess the number Game" in C

Tags: beginner, c, number-guessing-game

Just started learning C. I hope my code adheres to best practices and idioms

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
int iRandomNum;
int iGuess;
srand(time(NULL));

iRandomNum = (rand() % 10);
printf("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
scanf("%d", &iGuess);

// isdigit function expects a character so the guess value has to be ascii value of the digit character 
iGuess += 48;
if (isdigit(iGuess)){
    iGuess -=48; // change back to the original value for comparison with random number
    if (iGuess == iRandomNum){   
        printf("You Guessed Correctly\n");
     }    
    else{
        printf("The correct answer was %d\n",iRandomNum);
        printf("You guessed %d\n",iGuess);
     }   
 }   
 else{
      printf("This is not a digit!\n");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have observed a few things that may help you improve your code.

### Use consistent formatting

The code as posted has inconsistent indentation which makes it hard to read and understand. Pick a style and apply it consistently.

### Check return values for errors

The call to `scanf` can fail.  You can check the return values to make sure they haven't or your program may crash (or worse) when given malformed input or due to low system resources.  Rigorous error handling is the difference between mostly working versus bug-free software.  You should strive for the latter.

### Don't use Hungarian notation

Prefixing every variable with an abbreviation of its type is usually called "Hungarian notation" and it was once popular.  Even then it was a bad idea.  Don't clutter up your source code with that; instead, concentrate on defining meaningful names for each variable and choose types appropriately.  I'd suggest `secretNumber` and `userGuess` in this case.

### Use a better random number generator

You are currently using

```
iRandomNum = (rand() % 10);
```

There are a number of problems with this approach. The most significant problem is that the range this returns (0 through 9 inclusive) does not match what the user is asked to guess ("a number between 1 and 10")  Second, this will generate lower numbers more often than higher ones -- it's not a uniform distribution.  Another problem is that the low order bits of the random number generator are not particularly random, so neither is the result.  On my machine, there's a slight but measurable bias toward 0 with that.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999075/generate-a-random-number-within-range/2999130#2999130) for details, but I'd recommend changing that to

```
secretNumber = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 10) + 1;
```

### Think of the user

When someone asks me to "Guess a number between 1 and 10", I usually say [\$e\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).  (Yes, I'm afraid I'm that kind of person.)  It seems clear from the context of your program that what you really mean is to guess an integer, and it seems likely that, technically speaking, you don't want numbers solely *between* 1 and 10 but that you mean to include 1 and 10 among the possible choices.  To more clearly convey that, I'd suggest asking the user to "guess a whole number from 1 to 10 inclusive" but I'm probably too used to being around engineers and scientists.

### Check your logic

If I input `"e"` as my guess, the `scanf` call will fail and the variable may be uninitialized.

Comment: Tangential question from a fellow scientist: I always go with  pi instead of e. Have you found advantages to either?

Comment: That's a very insightful question.  In fact, I find that the advantage to choosing e over pi is that fewer people seem to have heard of e than pi, so choosing e yields dual advantages: 1) I can hold forth for untold hours expounding on the genius of Euler, the sublime beauty of Euler's identity, the constant e, natural logarithms and why all of it matters deeply to modern society and 2) nobody ever asks me again to pick a number.

Answer (score 7):

As Edward said:

> Pick a style and apply it consistently.

As with normal text, people will get discouraged working with you and giving feedback if the text you have written is messy.

Imagine:

> az wi Normal teXt pepls    ~~  DiscourageD w0rking wi you ++giving
>   feedback if zee teXT y heff vritten is mezzy.

Here is [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20161231104221/https://manual.cs50.net/style/) as an example of a style (from an introductory CS course). There should be an updated version [here](https://manual.cs50.net/style/) soon.

I am also learning `C` and tried to make your code consistent to the aforementioned style.

Is it not easier on the eye now?

```
/**
 * Guessing Game 
 * Here goes some description...
 * .....
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Initalize variables
    int random_num;
    int guess;

    // Add comment here
    srand(time(NULL));
    random_num = (rand() % 10);

    // Add comment here
    printf("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    // isdigit function expects a character so the guess value has to be 
    // ascii value of the digit character 
    guess += 48;
    if (isdigit(guess))
    {
        // change to the orig value and compare with random_num
        guess -= 48; 

        // Add comment here
        if (guess == random_num)
        {   
            printf("You Guessed Correctly\n");
        }    
        else
        {
            printf("The correct answer was %d\n", random_num);
            printf("You guessed %d\n", guess);
        }   
    }   
    else
    {
        printf("This is not a digit!\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Write what you mean

```
guess += 48;
if (isdigit(guess)) {
    guess -= 48;
```

Not only could the be simplified to `if (isdigit(guess + 48)) {` but it obfuscates two things:

- That you want to add the ASCII code of the `0` character. Use `'0'` instead of `48` here.
- That you actually want to check if `guess` lies between 0 and 9 which you can do much more concisely and readably with:

  ```
  if (guess >= 0 && guess <= 9) {
  ```

This is equivalent (see below) to the previous check but *inconsistent* with the requested number range „between 1 and 10“.

### Avoid the invocation of undefined behaviour

The [manual page of `isdigit(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3.html) says that the input value of the function

> must have the value of an `unsigned char` or `EOF` […].

In your program the user of your program enters a number, `scanf` stores it in the variable `guess` which is later handed to `isdigit`. If `guess` is outside of the range specified above, the program behaviour is *undefined*. In theory that means the function may perform arbitrary operations for these cases. In practice it means that you can't rely on its return value in these cases.

As an example, the specification in the manual allows the implementation of `isdigit` to truncate its input value to the least significant 8 bits (after checking for `EOF`) and looks up the character class in a table of length 256 (which is a sensible and realistic implementation because there are 256 different `unsigned char` values); in that case an input value 256 would be transformed and then truncated to (256 + 48) % 256 = 48 which is the ASCII code of a digit character even though 256 is not between 0 and 9.

Comment: Excellent point about `isdigit`.  Good catch!